# Como fazer com que, ao selecionar um checkbox, não seja possível selecionar outros?

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho esses 3 checkbox

```
<td style="background-color: #D6FAFA"><input type="checkbox" name="box2" id="ok" /></td>
<td style="background-color: #D6FAFA"><input type="checkbox" name="box2" id="nok"/></td>
<td style="background-color: #D6FAFA"><input type="checkbox" name="box2" id="na"/></td>
```

Ao marcar um checkbox com o id = ok eu não consiga marcar os outros dois checkbox e fazer a mesma coisa com os outros checkbox, ou seja só vou conseguir marcar se tiver tudo desmarcado se um deles tiver marcado os outros travam

eu tentei isso não deu certo

```
$(function() {
  enable_cb();
  $("#ok").click(enable_cb);
  $("#nok").click(enable_cb);
  $("#na").click(enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("#nok").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#na").attr("disabled",true);
  } else {
     $("#nok").removeAttr("disabled");    
     $("#na").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

alguém pode me dizer o que esta errando, estou usando a biblioteca jquery.v1.9.1.

Comment: Porque não usa Radio buttons? http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Comment: @Miguel É um padrão estranho mesmo com botões radio. O que ele quer é desabilitar as escolhas uma vez que uma foi feita. Não consigo imaginar um formulário no qual isso faça sentido. Se a ideia é um elemento que, ao ser clicado, mude o estado da aplicação, talvez seja melhor um botão ou um link mesmo.

Answer (score 5):

Semanticamente o mais correto é usar `input type="radio"`. Esse tipo de input escolhe por defeito só um, a regra é que todos têm de ter o mesmo `name`. A única coisa que esse tipo não permite é desmarcar todos.

Se precisas dessa funcionalidade podes usar assim com `type="checkbox"`:

```
var inputs = $('[type="checkbox"]'); // colocar os inputs em cache
inputs.on('click', function() { // juntar auscultador de evento
    inputs.get().forEach(function(el) { // iterar com a array nativa
        el.checked = el == this && this.checked; // marcar ou desmarcar o elemento iterado
    }, this);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cfjpkkey/

Comment: A princípio, eu sugeriria isso, mas me parece que o que ele quer é desabilitar as outras opções, como no jsFiddle da resposta do Guerra. Só acho isso um padrão muito esquisito.

Answer (score 4):

Você poderia colocar uma classe pra agrupar esses checkbox que você quer trabalhar dai ficaria assim:

```js
    $(function(){
       $('input.checkgroup').click(function(){
          if($(this).is(":checked")){
             $('input.checkgroup').attr('disabled',true);
             $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
          }else{
             $('input.checkgroup').removeAttr('disabled');
          }
       })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkgroup" id="ok"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkgroup" id="nok"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkgroup" id="na"/>
```

Fiddle: [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/sj4oyqv3/)